# Solve differential equation $(y-x)\sqrt{1+x^2}y' = \sqrt[3]{1+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Help me to solve differential equation:
$$(y-x)\sqrt{1+x^2}y' = \sqrt[3]{1+y^2}$$

I can't think of a way to substitute a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this replacement will help
$$x=\sinh(t)  $$ $dx=\cosh(t)dt $
$$y=\sinh(m) $$ $dy=\cosh(m)dm $
$$(\sinh(t)-\sinh(m))\cosh(t)\frac{\cosh(m)dm}{\cosh(t)dt}=\cosh^{\frac{3}{2}}(m) $$
$$ \Rightarrow$$
$$\frac{\sinh(t)-\sinh(m)}{\sqrt{\cosh(m)}}=\frac{dt}{dm} $$ 
Then you need to find a solution $t(m) $ and make a reverse replacement

Comment: What are $sh$ and $ch$? Hyperbolic sine and cosine?

Comment: Yes they are,but I think there is a better replacement than this

Comment: Isn't the exponent on the RHS (third to last line) $\frac23$?